# Refreshing Sonar violations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project I code on using Eclipse, with the Sonar plugin installed. When I do a commit, Jenkins starts a build that invokes Sonar. The Sonar server is then up to date. However, the violations in Eclipse are not up to date. I know about local analysis, but that be cumbersome to do for each module, plus the server already ran an update, I just need to find a way to have Eclipse refresh the violations from the server. The modules are associated with Sonar and the server just fine. Is this possible to refresh the violations or should I be doing something differently (to work around this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the "Refresh" icon of the "Violations" view to force the update: 
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Browsing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse+-+Prior+to+version+3.2#BrowsingSonarQubeinEclipse-Priortoversion32-ViolationsViewdisplayslocalorremoteinformationdependingontheselectedmode

Comment: Why can't I do this in any of the other SONAR menu and object contributions? I'm used to working with the Java perspective only (especially with the global problems view), so I have never come across this menu item up to now. Please add that also in the project context menu in the SONAR sub menu (or at another appropriate place).

Comment: Thanks Fabrice, that worked for me and updated all violations across all modules/projects. I have to agree with _Bananeweizen_, this option makes sense in the context menu - which is where I went looking in the first place. How about rather than greying out _Run local analysis_, when remote mode is active, replace it with _Refresh from server_?

Comment: Indeed guys, feel free to open a JIRA ticket for this enhancement (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE)

Comment: Thanks again Fabrice, in this case I'm guilty of not looking hard enough for the bugtracker. Here's the ticket I created: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-373